# Why is there no UIActivity for Flickr?

Tags: ios, flickr, uiactivity

A large variety of UIActivities have been published to provide support for additional services in iOS:

https://github.com/shu223/UIActivityCollection

Why has no Flickr UIActivity been published? Googling yields almost no mention of this. I'm guessing there's something about the Flickr authentication that does not play nice with UIActivityController but I'd appreciate any additional info. Numerous blogs have reported 'possible' Flickr integration in iOS 7 but I can't wait for that and I'd prefer to use UIActivityController over ObjectiveFlickr or ShareKit. Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason you can't make your own UIActivity for Flickr.  UIActivities can be used to kick off any sort of flow in your app.

Comment: Is your question: why hasn't someone else already done this for me? If you look at the code from some of the examples on github, you should have a good idea for where to start to implement an activity controller for Flickr.

Comment: @stevekohs: My concern is that, given the wide variety of UIActivities that have already been published, there is a good reason why no one has created one for Flickr as of yet. Some of the ones already published are for services that are much more obscure. If the reason really is no one has gotten around to it yet, great! That's all I need to know. But I thought I'd check and see if anyone had any other insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your question, there is support for Flickr in iOS. From UIKit/UIActivity.h:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypePostToFlickr       NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

And as the others mentioned, you're free to build your own UIActivity subclass which supports Flickr uploading as well. For that I would suggest the note on subclassing UIActivity in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011974).

Comment: yes, this question really isn't very relevant now that iOS 7 is out. Thanks.